# What does `gtag('js', new Date());` do in snippet proviced by gtag.js

Tags: google-analytics

quotation from https://developers.google.com/gtagjs/reference/api

> gtag(<command>, <command parameters>);
>
> <command> is one of three gtag commands: config, set, or event.

but snippet provided by https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs/ contains such line

> gtag('js', new Date());

What's her job?

Comment: I'm not sure.  My guess is that the date is used as a cache busting parameter.  See [What is cache busting? · Curtis Timson](https://curtistimson.co.uk/post/front-end-dev/what-is-cache-busting/) which has a section about using dates and times.   I'm not sure why you would have to pass the date into that function though.  I'd think it could just instantiate a new date on its own if it needed one for cache busting.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller, Or could it have something to do with [https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/6086069?hl=en] ?

Comment: Could be.   Again, I don't know why you would have to pass the date in for that either.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller, maybe serve as some kind of self-explanatory stuff

Answer (score 3):

It's for setting GA's cookie and reporting timezone/region/language to various functions responsible for functionality based on time...which is *a lot*. Most things in Google Analytics revolve around time in one way or another. For example session durations, time on page, the time of day that users visit your site, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Couldn't find more information out there but I think it could be like similar to `gtm.start` but for `gtag`. See more about `gtm.start` here: https://hume.dev/articles/gtm-start/
It might either be useful for tracking loading time (performance) or for serving as a seed for calculating unique ids per page load.